# How can I match this URL with java regex

Tags: java, regex

String url = "mysite.com/index.php?**id=12&id=432&id=145...**".

i have an url with multiple parameters that have the same name "id".i want to know how to match it with java regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that will match the parameter scheme you described:

```
((id=\d+&?)+id=\d+[^&])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yhBSLI6ZJhWPTx2d)

Comment: please how can i force it to not end with the & character?

Answer (score 1):

This regex should catch the ids

```
(id=\d+&?)*
```

Considering that, for some URLs you may not have ids appended.